# Enforce file permissions

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I have a directory where many users have write access and often the permissions on the directory changes. Is there a tool that lets me monitor the files for changes and enforce a specific file permission or any other way I can enforce this when users have write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if set the permissions for the group, instead of the user, it should work.

Have a look in the [chmod man page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

You can also set the group of the directory by using chgrp.

You can look in the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chgrp) for this command

Hope this helps

Comment: I know this, but I'm looking for something that can enforce the variables when it's on the user.

Comment: One easy thing and fast thing, depending on your needs, maybe you can create a script that runs from time to time and sets the permissions for all the sub directories and files.